# Searching user query in the ms graph api error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter= id eq '2837a21f-a9ef-4651-9502-2ec3e5cde425' or id eq 'bb5b696c-ad4c-436f-9a30-8fec3efaf8c8'

Getting the error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'id' of resource 'User'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "835e502f-325e-41aa-bf64-b7a8ae094a65",
            "date": "2019-02-13T10:13:13"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already the have the id of the user then why are using a filter ? even if it did work it would be the most inefficient way of doing it. Just do a batch request for each Id you want (or want to check if its exists) then you will get one or both of the users returned with one request and a lot quicker response because you not using a filter eg

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "url": "/users('150bb06c-1c9a-4ac2-8b55-8cf15854b555')",
      "method": "GET",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "url": "/users('23231114c-1c9a-4ac2-8b55-33333221')",
      "method": "GET",
      "id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We have gone through this concept 'Json Batching' earlier too. Just curious to know why our query was not working.

Some other queries are working like
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter= id eq '2837a21f-a9ef-4651-9502-2ec3e5cde425'

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$filter= id eq '2837a21f-a9ef-4651-9502-2ec3e5cde425' or id eq 'bb5b696c-ad4c-436f-9a30-8fec3efaf8c8'

Comment: I would say its specifically not supported because of the performance and resource issues such a query could cause, if you allow people to do using Or on a query like that you would have some dev's trying to chaining 100's or Id's.